# How do I install an ASP.NET MVC 5 Web application manually on IIS 7.5 and connect to database?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis, iis-7.5

I am trying to install an ASP.NET 5 Web application on IIS 7.5, and am running into a database connection issue. When running the application in the development environment the data source is set to `(LocalDB)\v11.0`, Which I believe is not correct. I get an error when browsing the web application on the remote server where IIS is located,

The system cannot find the file specified:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
```

How do I form the connection string so that my application can reach the database to match models I created with the entity framework in `Visual Studio 2013`?

I think something like this would be suitable:

```
<add name="MyDB" connectionString="data source=ServerName; initial catalog=MyDB; attachddbfilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf; integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your error, it looks like you don't have a local database runtime installed.

If you are going to use SQL Server Express 2012, you will need to download and run the installer [SqlLocalDB.MSI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) and use the connection string `(LocalDB)\v11.0`.

If you are going to use SQL Server Express 2014, you will need to download the 2014 installer [SqlLocalDB.MSI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299) and use the new connection string `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`.

Comment: I would like to use SQL Server on the machine where would I install the app, how would do that?

Comment: Follow the link provided in my answer to the version you are interested in (2012 or 2014). Once you click 'Download' you will see a list of the 32-bit and 64-bit version of the tools and server installations for SQL Server Express. Choose the desired installation and run it.

Comment: I cannot install SQL Server express, any other options?

Comment: Cannot install? Meaning, you don't have permission, or it's outside the project scope? Are you attempting to install the server or the runtime? You only need to install the LocalDb runtime. Look for the file "SqlLocalDB.msi" after you click 'Download'.

Comment: I do not have permission, so, I wondering if it is possible to modify the connection string to access the database with the existing .mdf files I have in the project.